# avoiding simultaneous write on NFS shared text file

Tags: c++, locking, nfs, inotify, stat

I am writing a module in C++ that will run on a cluster of machines, all of which have a nfs mounted file storage.

I have a configuration file shared with all the machines via NFS; and all can read/write that file. How do I make sure there is no data corruption due to simultaneous access?

I am aware of NFS having its own protocol for locking, but I see its not reliable -[concurrent nfs access](https://superuser.com/questions/33525/concurrent-nfs-access). I also see that iNotify does not fare well on nfs mounted drives - [inotifiy example](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/04/inotify-c-program-example/). I am not sure  [stat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) will be useful to check if a file is being accessed before writing/reading.

How do I implement a simple locking mechanism in c++ to avoid simultaneous access?

Comment: ... by not attempting to write to the same file simultaneously. Write to a unique copy of the file and pivot over the old file using rename.

Comment: ...in other words, exactly the same thing as you should probably be doing anyway if the file was local.

Comment: this is not an option for me, as the file (with its fd) is being tracked by an IPC (unix domain socket) for changes. the changes are transferred back to the module for further processing.

Comment: In that case your best option is probably to stop using NFS and get a cluster-aware file system that supports cluster-wide file locking in a more reliable manner than the not-designed-for-this-usage NFS locking (which as noted can be unreliable on top of not being intended to handle this kind of thing).

Comment: that is again not an option for me - i am specifically looking for suggestions that would help me design a locking mechanism

Answer (score 0):

When you write contents A, B and C at the same time to a file shared over NFS, the final contents would either be A B C or any such possible combination of A B C like B A C, C A B, etc. The file will always be consistent, it will never write A partially, followed by B. Thus write happen one after the other. Note, this will be true only when content size falls within NFS block size.

If your write exceeds the block size, you need to use NLM which requires to run lock daemon both on the NFS server and client.

Comment: I didn't frame the question headline right, my bad, I would like to avoid simultaneous 'access', not just the writes. Even though simultaneous writes wont be an issue, simultaneous read/write will be. A locking mechanism to avoid that is what I am interested in.